# Can't change status code in custom middleware .net 7 minimal API

Tags: middleware, .net-7.0, minimal-apis

I'm writing a middleware to change status code to BadRequest when received business notification messages from my domain, but I getting the message "StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started".

In the catch block everything is fine, at least it's working.

this is my code:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        var response = context.Response;
        var statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";

        try
        {
            await next(context);

            if (_notificationContext.HasNotifications)
            {
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

                var resultNotifications = new Result<Notification>() { Errors = new List<Notification>() };
                resultNotifications.Errors.AddRange(_notificationContext.Notifications);

                await response.WriteAsync(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(resultNotifications));
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            var correlationId = response.Headers["X-Correlation-ID"].FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
            Result<Notification> resultNotifications = null;
            if (_notificationContext.HasNotifications)
            {
                statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                resultNotifications = new Result<Notification>() { Errors = new List<Notification>() };
                resultNotifications.Errors.AddRange(_notificationContext.Notifications);
                using (LogContext.PushProperty("Notifications", resultNotifications.Errors, true))
                {
                    Log.Error(exception, "There are validation notifications to be analyzed.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Error(exception, "An error occurred with the request. See the log for more details.");
            }

            if (!response.HasStarted)
            {
                response.StatusCode = statusCode;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(resultNotifications ?? GetErrorMessage(correlationId)));
            }
        }

    }
```

I expect this result with status code 400:

```
{
    "Data": null,
    "Errors": [
        {
            "Key": "Token",
            "Message": "Token de autenticação de autenticação do MarketPlace Liberty",
            "Alerta": false
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'm receiving this with status code 200:

```
{
    "requestId": "62BD6460AC644A37A68F912FCAC8DA7F",
}{
    "Data": null,
    "Errors": [
        {
            "Key": "Token",
            "Message": "Token de autenticação de autenticação do MarketPlace Liberty",
            "Alerta": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestion to fix this or other solution to getting these notifications?

Comment: Have you cheked if the `_notificationContext.HasNotifications` blocks has been executed? Or which section has been executed?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, This line `response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;` causes error

Comment: Please provide a [mre] or at least provide the middleware registrations (i.e. contents of `Program.cs`).

Comment: I put a sample on my github [link](https://github.com/alexanlp/ExceptionMiddewareExample)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-webapplication)

> Warning
>
> Don't call next. Invoke after the response has been sent to the client.
> Changes to HttpResponse after the response has started throw an
> exception. For example, setting headers and a status code throw an
> exception. Writing to the response body after calling next:
>
> May cause a protocol violation. For example, writing more than the
> stated Content-Length. May corrupt the body format. For example,
> writing an HTML footer to a CSS file. HasStarted is a useful hint to
> indicate if headers have been sent or the body has been written to.

Using your [Example](https://github.com/alexanlp/ExceptionMiddewareExample), I would  refactor this by removing the middleware and make use of [Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/min-api-filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#validate-an-object-with-a-filter):

```
app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    var forecast =  Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
}).AddEndpointFilter(async (efiContext, next) =>
    {
       
        var result = await next(efiContext);
        //add check if has notifications here
        return Results.BadRequest(new { key = "Key", message = "Validation message" }); 
        
    })
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.WithOpenApi();
```

From the above snippet I'm discarding the object `result` and creating a new object to be returned with the `BadRequest` response, preferably to make this cleaner you should figure out a way to evaluate this check `if (_notificationContext.HasNotifications)` before starting any response such that in your filter or middleware :

```
if (_notificationContext.HasNotifications)
    //return bad request
else
    await next(context);
```

Comment: My thinking was create a global middleware for all endpoints. Your suggest works and I'll go research a solution to create a global filter then. Thanks a lot